# How to filter result with another model values - django restframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 4 tables:

```
Book:
 - id
 - name
 - user_id #(ForeignKey)
 - visitor_id #(ForeignKey)

Car:
 - id
 - name
 - user_id #(ForeignKey)
 - visitor_id #(ForeignKey)

Pen:
 - id
 - name
 - user_id #(ForeignKey)
 - visitor_id #(ForeignKey)

Role:
 - id
 - obj_type #(ChoicesField. equals `1`,`2` or `3`)
 - obj_id
 - obj_role #(Boolean)
 - visitor_id #(ForeignKey)
```

Now I have this in serializer:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    queryset = Book.objects.filter(?!?!?) # Here I need help
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

I want to check `Role` table and filter `Book` according to `Role` results. How I can do this? What's best solution?

I want something like this:

```
queryset = Book.objects.filter(
    ID__in(Role.objects.filter(user=request.user, obj_id=book_id, role__gt=0))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define `get_queryset` method:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        # current user is self.request.user
        return self.queryset.filter(....)
```

for example if you want to only let the owner of a book to see/edit that book:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    # ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.pk)
```

update: you need something like this:

```
items = Role.objects.filter(user=request.user, role__gt=0).values_list("pk", flat=True)
return self.queryset.filter(pk__in=items)
```

Comment: How I can check role per Book?

Comment: I need to add this checking for per row: `Role.objects.filter(user=request.user, role__gt=0, obj_id=Book.id)` ?!